# Using bin feature in crosstabulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

```
labs = ['small','medium','big','large']
df['size'] = pd.qcut(df.volume,4,labels=labs)
pd.crosstab(df.size,df.cut,margins=True,normalize='columns')
#cut and volume are columns/features of df Dataframe
```

Above is the snippet I tried to execute. This is the output I got

```
cut     Fair    Good    Ideal   Premium     Very Good   All
row_0                       
539430  1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
```

But I expected ['small','medium','big','large'] as indices.
How can I get them as indices?
I also tried changing type of df.size from category to string. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need swap columns, also better is use `[]` instead dot notation if columns names are like methods in pandas like [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cut':['Fair', 'Good'] * 3, 'volume':[1, 5, 10, 29, 30, 2]})

labs = ['small','medium','big','large']
df['size'] = pd.qcut(df.volume,4,labels=labs)

#there is 18 values in df
print (df.size)
18    

df1 = pd.crosstab(df.size,df.cut,margins=True,normalize='columns')
print (df1)
cut    Fair  Good  All
row_0                 
18      1.0   1.0  1.0
```

---

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['cut'], df['size'],margins=True,normalize='columns')
print (df2)
size  small  medium  big  large  All
cut                                 
Fair    0.5     0.0  1.0    0.5  0.5
Good    0.5     1.0  0.0    0.5  0.5
```